# Gnuplot set title dynamically

Tags: gnuplot, ns-3

I am trying to set the title of my gnuplot chart from the last line in my .dat file but I am not sure what to do.

My .dat file reads like:

```
Column1 Column2
1 0.5
2 1.5
3 2.5
4 3.5
5 4.5
6 5.5   
Average is ??????
```

Would anyone know the command to set the title using the text of the last line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gnuplot allows for shell-style backtick expansion.  Combining that with the unix utility `tail` should work just fine:

```
set title "`tail -1 myfile.dat`"
plot 'myfile.dat' u 1:2
```